# Ng-reapeat selects input de todos forms mudam junto

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá,

Sou iniciante com AngularJS, e estou tendo problemas com o ng-repeat:

O usuário pode inserir um trecho de um formulario quantas vezes quiser mas em cada um deles deve ser possivel selecionar opções diferentes.

Coloquei o ng-reapet, mas acontece qua a opção que seleciono em qualquer um dos trechos replicados, muda automaticamente os outros selects iguais dos outros trechos também

http://jsfiddle.net/yfj68juq/

```
<div ng-app="icmssProdutos" ng-controller="IcmssProdutosController">
  <div ng-repeat="icms in ICMSs">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <label for="ex2">Regime</label>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected.regime" ng-options="r.regime for r in data">
        <option value="">Selecione o Regime</option>
      </select>
      <label for="ex2" ng-show="selected.regime">Situação Tributária
        <select class="form-control" ng-show="selected.regime" ng-model="selected.situacao" ng-options="s.situacao for s in selected.regime.SituacaoTributaria">
          <option value="">Selecione a Situação Tributária</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label for="ex2" ng-show="selected.regime">Origem
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected.Origem" ng-options="o.Origem for o in selected.regime.Origens">
          <option value="">Selecione a Origem do Produto</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="IncluirICMS()">INCLUIR</button>
</div>
```

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, está gerando formulários dinamicamente, ou seja, tem mais de um. Coloque a parte do código que também gera os formulários, sem isso não temos como simular o seu problema (que provavelmente é de escopo).

Comment: @GabrielKatakura, obrigada por responder. Veja o fiddle todo o código para essa ação http://jsfiddle.net/yfj68juq/ na verdade é apenas um trecho do form que vai ser replicado não o form inteiro

Comment: Depois de dar um push no seu objeto, delete ele. delete $scope.data

Comment: Obrigada @PauloGustavo desta forma, ao clicar no botão incluir, os selects não estão funcionando http://jsfiddle.net/x8mcrkju/3/

Comment: @Gih, talvez o problema que está acontecendo é que a mesma lista que você adicionar é a lista que "lista" os icms. Tente armazenar isso em outro lugar, outra lista. Veja se isso resolve seu problema: http://jsfiddle.net/x8mcrkju/4/ Perceba que eu coloquei o {{selecionados}} para mostrar todos os objetos que tem dentro da lista

Comment: Obrigada @PauloGustavo mas desta forma como faço para acessar os dados de `{{selecionados}}` e organizar em uma tabela por exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme o [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yfj68juq/) que foi passado, todos os **ICMS** estavam operando encima do mesmo objeto, o **selected**. Para solucionar o problema, bastava remover o **selected** (que é desnecessário nesse caso), e aproveitar a variável **icms** do **ng-repeat**. Assim cada um ira operar com o seu objeto. Aqui está a solução:

http://jsfiddle.net/zbdvke2w/1/

Comment: Obrigada isso resolveu :D Se for possivel responder, como faço faço para ter a ação de remover caso a pessoa desista de colocar o imposto?

Comment: Basta colocar um botão que ao clicar no mesmo, ele remova o objeto ICMS da propriedade $scope.ICMSs.

Comment: Com ng-remove?? `<button style="float:right "type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-remove="icms">x</button>`  http://jsfiddle.net/zbdvke2w/2/

Comment: Não, você tem que criar um botão e associar ele em um evento que faça essa ação de removerIcms.
http://jsfiddle.net/zbdvke2w/3/

Comment: Obrigada  funciona perfeitamente, mas não entendi o que faz exatamente estas duas partes da function(icms):   `.indexOf(icms);` e `.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Muito obrigada Gabriel